# Memory leak in transmission-deamon?

Tags: kernel, transmission, memory-leak

My system had a scare last night, it apparently ran out of memory, the rtkit-deamon complained about the canary thread starving and the kernel killed a number of processes.

The system is a Fujitsu Esprimo with an Intel i5-4570 4-core CPU and 32 GB of RAM.

I noticed in the syslog the list of tasks that were running. The biggest was transmission-deamon that reported 8,132,465 pages vm in use (see below). When one page is 4K, then this adds up to 32G. It also did kill it. It seems logical to wach this process in the coming period. I did notice the MemAvailable value in /proc/meminfo decrease steadily from 32G to 0 in about 2 weeks time.

What would be a good method to track this? When I look in /proc/$PID/mem, it is empty. Is vsz from ps a good thing to watch?

```
Nov 29 04:35:30 primo kernel: [1348176.819869] Tasks state (memory values in pages):
Nov 29 04:35:30 primo kernel: [1348176.819870] [  pid  ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
Nov 29 04:35:30 primo kernel: [1348176.819917] [    888]   132   888  8132465  7183145 61280256   428000             0 transmission-da
Nov 29 04:35:30 primo kernel: [1348176.820173] Out of memory: Killed process 888 (transmission-da) total-vm:32529860kB, anon-rss:28732580kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:132 pgtables:59844kB oom_score_adj:0
```

Comment: you need to be precise: what version of transmission. what version of Ubuntu.  example: https://github.com/transmission/transmission/issues/3077   v3 with 22.04 seems to do this.

Comment: I knew I forgot somehting. Yes 22.04.3 and 3.00.
Odd that when the issue has been known for 1.5 years and when transmission itself is already up to v4, it is still not in the Ubuntu repository.

Comment: Transmission 4 is in the Ubuntu 23.10 repositories. 22.04 using v3 is not odd at all: Unchanging software is a key feature of LTS releases.

Comment: Then there is a flaw in the process somewhere. You can't have a program that is known to cause problems in an LTS release. Apparently it wasn't tested properly enough before it got included and once it's in, you might have the same software version for a long time, but what good is that if it breaks your system. Somehow it doesn't add up.

Comment: To me this looks like an issue with the ppl from transmission. If you follow the link and the links in there this is never fixed. Instead a workaround was found and a new release got issued (v4 has it fixed) and nobody cared about v3 after that. And there was never a CVE about this problem so it never reached a bug tracker, never got an update.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this myself - yes Transmission 3 on Ubuntu 22.04 has some [serious memory leaks](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/issues/3077). However, the issue has vanished for me when I moved on to Transmission 4.

I'm running Transmission in a Docker container, to separate it from the OS (and thus be able to run a newer version without any dependency issues).

Personally I'm using this container:

- [haugene/transmission-openvpn](https://hub.docker.com/r/haugene/transmission-openvpn/) (which has OpenVPN running inside the container along with Transmission - and the author also has a variant with Wireguard instead)

If you just want to run Transmission alone, I can recommend the Docker images from LinuxServer.io:

- [linuxserver/transmission](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/transmission) (Vanilla Tranmission, but with lots of configuration tweaks)